# Enable LD_PRELOAD just for BASh after system startup

Tags: c, linux, bash, pam, ld-preload

Is there a way to inject/enable LD_PRELOAD just for new sessions (ie: `BASh`)?

I have a syntax highlighting library that I want to have automatically enabled (ie: highlight warnings for certain users), and just need it loaded for `BASh` rather than all processes. If I put it in `/etc/ld.so.preload`, it's disruptive and causes issues for all the system services and other programs that don't need it running, wrapping system calls (`printf` and `exec` mainly).

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you care whether the library is preloaded when `bash` is run in non-interactive mode?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I would want the library to always be run, regardless of interactive/non-interactive mode. Thank you, BTW>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to replace `bash` with a shell script that performs the `LD_PRELOAD` logic, then calls the actual (renamed) `bash` binary.

That is, move `/bin/bash` to `/bin/bash.original`, then create a script `/bin/bash` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/my/library.so
export LD_PRELOAD
exec /bin/bash.original "$@"
```

You could include logic here (e.g., "is stdout a tty") if you want to only perform the `LD_PRELOAD` when connected to an interactive session.  Trying to perform any sort of terminal manipulation when bash isn't connected to a tty will probably yield weird results.

Comment: I was hashing out a solution along these lines myself.  Note that as it presently stands, however, this solution does not meet the OP's requirement to avoid preloading his library for binaries other than `bash`, since the `LD_PRELOAD` variable in the shell's environment will be inherited by processes it spawns.

Comment: There's not really a good way around that, since processes will always inherit the environment of their parent.  Either `LD_PRELOAD` is set in bash's environment (and children thereof), or it's not.  Possibly you could modify `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/profile` or similar to explicitly unset the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Maybe I could use `procfs` to check the process image in the library so it doesn't enable certain functionality for child processes? My biggest concern is preventing the library from being loaded by system daemons/services, breaking them. This issue is especially pronounced on CentOS, which seems to break (not boot properly) if I set `/etc/ld.so.preload` with just a very minimalist library.

Comment: One could imagine using the appropriate shell startup file(s) to unexport `LD_PRELOAD` after the shell starts, to avoid it being inherited by subsequent processes.  No doubt such a mechanism can be defeated, but that might not be a concern.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Within the startup code for `library.so`, clean out the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable.  And note that setting `LD_PRELOAD` to point to library by its full path will break any binary that's not the same architecture - for example, if `/path/to/my/library.so` is a 32-bit library, most 64-bit processes run with that envval set will fail (binaries like setuid binaries that ignore LD_PRELOAD might work).

Comment: @larsks Unfortunately, this approach does not work. It triggers all local/SSH sessions to generate the following error: `-bash: /bin/bash: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links`

Comment: Right, you will need to use `#!/bin/bash.original` if `/bin/sh` is a symlink.  This is distribution-dependent (in many cases, `/bin/sh` is not a symlink to `bash`).

Comment: @AndrewHenle How would be the best (most portable) approach to cleaning out `LD_PRELOAD`? Just `setenv` the value to `NULL`?

Comment: @DevNull, do you anticipate a problem with using `unsetenv()`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger After going through the calls I'm wrapping, nope. I'll go with `unsetenv()`. Thanks.

Comment: @DevNull [`unsetenv( "LD_PRELOAD" );`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unsetenv.html) should work, as long as it's simply that single library.  If the variable is more complex you'll need to parse and recreate it without the library you want to remove.

Comment: I tried the above approach, but in the end, I wind up with the same problem where too much of the system uses the `LD_PRELOAD`ed library unintentionally. I think I'll still need to incorporate `PAM` so I can differentiate between user sessions and startup tasks, unless there's a better tool/framework for accomplishing this.